# How do you count the number of a certain digit with Scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme

I need to make a recursive procedure that finds how many 6's are in a number. For example, 606 has two 6's. I started it.

```
(define num
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
       ((< n 0) (num (- n)))
       ((= n 0) 0)
       ((> n 6)
```

I do not want to convert anything. Is there a way of dividing it by 10, then if the decimal is .6 add one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  For integer division in scheme, use the *quotient* function, as in (quotient 9 2) gives 4.
2)  For integer modulus in scheme, use the *remainder* function, as in (remainder 9 2) gives 1.

Scheme is based on recursion, as you stated.  To solve a recursive problem, you have to state the solution in terms of a smaller instances of the problem:
"The number of 6 digits in a number N is ... "
and for ... you state the solution in terms of the solution of part of N.

The easiest part of N to recur on is N/10, which is all but the last digit of N.  Then, to solve this recursively, you should assume that you know the answer to (num (quotient N 10)).  Call that value X.  How does knowing N and X tell you how many digits is in N?

If the last digit of N is 6, then the solution is X+1.  Otherwise, the solution is X.  How can you tell if the last digit is 6?  Use the remainder function.

```
(define (num N)
  ; check cases
  (cond

  ; case 1) negative condition
    ((< N 0) (num (- N)))

  ; case 2) zero condition, the terminal case
    ((= N 0) 0)

  ; case 3) recursive case with a 6 as the last digit
    ((= (remainder N 10) 6) (+ X 1))

  ; case 4) recursive case without a 6 as the last digit
    (#t X)
))
```

Now you just have to substitute the recursive assumption in for X, so for example case 3 becomes

```
; case 3
((= (remainder N 10) 6) (+ (num (quotient N 10)) 1))
```

Change X for case 4 as well and you'll get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Almost as good, let me introduce you to `modulo`. It takes in two numbers, and returns the remainder of the first divided by the second. Taking the `(modulo n 10)` will return the last digit of `n`. The general Scheme (ba-duh-duh-chiiing) for what you want is

```
(define num-6s
    (lambda (n)
       (cond
          ((< n 10)
              ; Base Case, if n = 6, then 1 else 0
          ((= (modulo n 10) 6)
             ; The last digit of n is 6
          (else
             ; The last digit of n isn't 6
             ))))
```

Now as another helpful hint, `(floor (/ n 10))` drops the last digit of a number. This is how you should get the next number to recurse upon.

Comment: @user2780598 Anytime, If you find my answer helpful, you can check the check beside my answer, it marks the question as solved and takes it off the list of unanswered questions.